# Steel to aluminum structural equivalent

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, structural-analysis, design, automotive-engineering

I am trying to build an aluminum trailer on an airbag suspension. The plans are for a steel frame and we are looking to construct it out of aluminum to save weight due to towing limitations. Not sure how to upload and insert plans here, so I will try to elaborate as best I can.

Tray dimensions are 81" x 216" The steel frame is 3/16" x 2" x 3" rectangular tubing. There will be 4 lengths of tubing running through the entire 18' with centerlines at 1" 20" 68" 80" Widthwise, there are 10 crossmembers spaced approximately 24" apart. This will be fully welded and overlaid with 1/8" diamond plate for a deck. It is tandem axle and will be used to haul 1 5000lbs vehicle with a 113" wheelbase.

Can anybody tell me what the equivalent aluminum tubing would be to use in lieu of the 3/16" it calls for and the 1/8" plate as decking? Should note the alloy would be 6061-T6 and plate is either 3003-H22/24 or 6061-T6. I am looking to create a lightweight and strong car hauler to safely carry vehicles over 1000s of miles.

Thank you to everyone reading this and please ask for any clarification necessary.

Comment: I think you should at least sketch a diagram of the geometry and forces involved. The equivalence is not a straightforward as saying one is X times stronger than the other.